# Is the following variant of the "je ... , desto/umso" construction acceptable?

Tags: word-order

> 1 : **Je** früher du kommst, **desto** mehr Zeit haben wir.
>
> OK? : Wir haben **desto** mehr Zeit, **je** früher du kommst.
>
> 2 : **Je** länger er unterwegs war, **umso** besser gefiel ihm das Land.
>
> OK? : Das Land gefiel ihm **umso** besser, **je** länger er unterwegs war.

Not only is the normal word order of "je" and "desto/umso" is switched around, but the "desto/umso" clause is also not inverted.

It almost seems as if the speaker had not initially intended to use this "the more ... , the more" sentence constuction but rather it was sort of an afterthought.

Comment: All your examples are perfectly acceptable. Switching the order of clauses (that's what you did) almost never changes the meaning of the sentence but only the emphasis, which rests on the leading clause.

Comment: [This site](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-je-je-desto-umso-a-435248.html) confirms that the inversion is possible but to me as a native speaker it sounds unusual.

Comment: To me it does not. Must be a regional thing.

Comment: When I was a child my parents taught me the order "umso ... desto". And the second sentence sounds very unfamiliar at least, if not "wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no professional background on that, but — though I’ve never seen *desto* in the first part of a sentence — I think they are both correct.

See also [desto](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/desto) and [umso in the Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umso).

Answer (score -1):

As a native German speaker, I do not have any professional background either. But I would say that the first example can not be turned around that easily.

With the second one I am not quite sure. It could be valid but I would rather say:

> Das Land gefiel ihm **immer** besser, **je** länger er unterwegs war.

I know that this would not match the "je" and "desto/umso" construct, but maybe it's helpful anyway.

Comment: Wenn man nicht so recht weiß und keine Begründung vorbringen kann, dann muss man nicht antworten. Was man selbst geschmacklich bevorzugen würde, das kann man auf einem Blog posten oder hier in einem Kommentar, wenn man etwas Reputation gesammelt hat.

Comment: ich vermutete, dass es dennoch hilfreich wäre. Bitte entschuldigen Sie der Herr